# How to patch an Ethernet cable for Internet connection?

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet-connection, patch, cat5

I recently need to fix damaged end of the Ethernet cable (CAT5). This is due to wear and tear, but this cable use to work with no problem out of the box. So, I bought the necessary tools like crimper and male jacks. Then, I watched videos after videos on How to do this. Then, I tried to match the wiring setup used on other end of the cable. I connected the cable no lights came on (orange or green blinking light at the Ethernet port). After that, I decided to follow the wiring T586-A as follows below.

[image]

At this point, orange and green light came on; Green light blinked away as if it was communicating, but when I looked at my system it reported that it has NO INTERNET CONNECTION but it kept trying to connect with no success. So, I thought maybe I need to use T-586B wiring diagram and I redid the connection again using T586B. When I plugged it in the socket, once again orange light came on and the green light started to blink away as if there was Internet Connection, but the computer system said NO INTERNET CONNECTION. I was bit confused. I tried the cable on another system. Again, that computer reported NO Internet Connection. However, as soon as I plugged the store bought cat5 cable. It works within few seconds and the computer has Internet connection. **So, again I thought I made a mistake in my wiring and try to follow this working CABLE wiring setup. Sadly, this too didn't work, even though ethernet port lights came on.**

Note: I didn't just patch this cable just once or twice in my attempts. I wasted about 15 ethernet jacks or 15 different times of attempts. None worked.

I followed the steps mentioned in my Internet Research and all them videos including the instructions that came with the crimper. So, I am bit confused.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: By the looks the one thing you forgot to buy, was a tester. This would tell you if you have wired it all correctly.

Comment: @Bib That's true... You think it will help.

Comment: I use that chart but I ALWAYS do both ends. There have been changes so make certain both ends are the same.

Comment: A tester is indispensable for doing your own wiring.

Comment: @John Hmmm that never crossed my mind. I should try that... thanks.

Comment: Note: 1) T-586B is by far the most common convention. 2) crimping your own ends is a 'fun beginner sport'. I've been doing it 30 years & still screw some up. When you're new, getting one in four to work is a fair result ;) Ironically, the newer you are to this, the more you need to spend on a good tester.

Comment: dont go overboard, while expensive testers have lots of fancy features, you dont need them just to test a cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, an ethernet cable tester - while not mandatory - will make your life much easier.

However in my opinion, just as important (if not more so) is a quality crimping tool ***AND*** RJ45 plugs.  Cheap ones will often result in bad cables.  You dont have to get top of the line, but dont go for the cheapest either.

Believe me, when you have made as many cables as I have that didnt work and someone gives you their quality crimping tool and plugs to use, your mind will be blown at how much easier and faster it is.  Not to mention you will make far, far fewer bad cables.

Answer (score 2):

With post-2000 consumer-grade hardware it doesn't really matter which scheme you use, because network devices will detect if you're using incorrect wiring scheme and "cross" the cable internally. Both writing schemes will work. Also, it doesn't matter of you use A or B - what matters is if both ends are done using the same scheme (technically cables using the same and different wiring schemes both have their specific use cases, and with professional-grade hardware it would matter).

That brings us to the probable issue: the other end may not follow neither the A or B scheme. In that case you would have to either wire the other end using the same non-standard scheme, or - and that's the better and easier way - make both ends follow the standard. Using non-standard schemes will only lead to confusion and more wasted time down the line.

It's also possible that one (or more) of the 8 wires is broken. You could check for continuity with a multimeter or some creative battery + LED set. Such cable could be wired for 100 Mbps Ethernet if you could find 2 working pairs (and by "pair" I mean two wires of the same color, one striped).